# How can I fix broken sudo - sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/ADSM near line 5?

Tags: sudo

```
$ sudo
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers.d/ADSM: Alias `TSMADM' already defined near line 5 <<<
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers.d/ADSM: Alias `TSMCMD' already defined near    line 18 <<<
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers.d/QUALY: Alias `TRSC' already defined near line 1 <<<
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers.d/QUALY: Alias `TRSCOPERATION' already defined near line 3 <<<
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers.d/RCCM: Alias `TCAINST' already defined near line 17 <<<
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers.d/RCCM: Alias `TCAUNINST' already defined near line 20 <<<
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers.d/RCCM: Alias `TADDM' already defined near line 23 <<<
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers.d/RCCM: Alias `TAD4D' already defined near line 24 <<<
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers.d/RCCM: Alias `RCCM' already defined near line 24 <<<
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers.d/TOP: Alias `NORSUDO' already defined near line 4 <<<
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers.d/TOP: Alias `NOVISUDO' already defined near line 4 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/ADSM near line 5
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Please provide me a solution to enter into the root to edit the `sudoers` file.

Comment: might be worth reading http://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-an-error-and-not-allowi

Comment: But those commands are asking for the smadmin password.And im not the admin for the system

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/ADSM near line 5
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

These lines indicate that only root (or someone else with UID 0) can fix this (by logging in and using `visudo`).

Comment: Correct, that's why I wrote "only root (or someone else with UID 0) can fix this".  If you have no access to a UID 0 account, boot from a CD, mount / and fix the file from there.

Answer (score 0):

If this caused in VM need to reboot the system.
if this is occured in cloud like instances then

> unmount the volume attached to the instance 
>   then attach to other instance
>   umount the volume
>   cd to the volume
>   edit sudoers file
>   save
>   exit the drive/volume
>   unmount
>   detach
>   attach to the first instance
>   mount
>   try sudo su -

it wll work i tried the same